# R: Assignment to match dimensions of target array

Tags: r, variable-assignment

Consider following snippet of code -

```
targetArray = array(Inf, dim=c(3,5))
targetArray
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf
[2,]  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf
[3,]  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf

temp = NA
data = rnorm(n = 15, mean = 2, sd = 2)
```

Now, if I assign `data` or `temp` to `targetArray`, it will alter the dimensions of `targetArray`. Is there any way to make sure that it doesn't happen?

```
targetArray = temp
targetArray
[1] NA

targetArray = data
targetArray
 [1]  2.4026814  2.4011577 -0.5089512  1.6223969  4.7533560  0.6619385 -0.5676509  1.3093745  1.2342189 -0.5368143  4.4641850  1.9515940  2.0025938 -1.1589229
[15]  1.6669973
```

How do I make sure that the assignment matches dimensions of `targetArray`? i.e. when I enter `targetArray = temp`, it should change all the elements of targetArray to `NA` without changing its dimensions. Similarly, for `targetArray = data`, it should realign 1 x 15 dimensional `data` vector to conform to dimensions of `targetArray` and assign it (either rowwise or columnwise).

Answer (score 1):

I think your expectations are a bit off. That assignment doesn't care what's on the LHS - you're not "filling-in" data into `targetArray`, but rather (usually copying and) assigning some data the name `targetArray`.

To get the result you want, just adjust the dimensions of the input data, e.g.

```
targetArray = matrix(data, ncol = ncol(targetArray), nrow = nrow(targetArray))
```

Comment: Thanks @eddi. I knew the suggestion you give, it's just that I can't use it for my code.

Comment: @eddy I basically have my a multidimensional `targetArray` with fixed dimensions. Also, I repeatedly do this assignment for different dimensions. Short answer, I can't change the dimensions, I'll have to explicitly check for mismatch in dimensions of target and source variables before the assignment takes place.

Comment: @steadyfish - sorry, I don't understand why you can't use the above code - it will keep the dimensions of your `targetArray` fixed on assignment

Comment: @eddy I haven't elaborated much the actual problem. Let me try to explain with a simpler example. Consider `targetArray` with dimensions `N x D`. I'm repeatedly assigning **some values** to `N` rows of this matrix. Ideally the **some values** are vectors with D elements. but, sometimes instead I get `NA` values (a single value) which is the pathological case here. For now, I've made the changes to the code so that even when I get `NA` values, I make sure it is a D-long vector of `NA` values which can be assigned. The suggestion you give does answer the OP above, but is not usable in my code.

Comment: @steadyfish I suspect you could use the fact that R recycles vectors to your advantage there, but it's hard to say without a specific workable example